# An integral representation of Riemann zeta function

Tags: limits, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

For $\mathrm{Re}(s)>-1$, $$-\zeta'(s)=\lim_{N\rightarrow{\infty}} -\frac{N^{1-s}\log N}{1-s}+\frac{N^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2}-\frac{1}{2}N^{-s}\log N+\sum_{n=1}^N \log(n)n^{-s}.$$
Please give me the proof of this formula.

Comment: That's impossible, the formula is wrong.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm sorry. I made a mistake. The last term is $$\sum_{n=1}^N \log(n)n^{-s}$$.

Comment: Show that for $\Re(s) > 1$ : $\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} =   \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N  \int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s})dx $ $=\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N  \int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s}- s (x-n) n^{-s-1})dx$

and that the last sequence converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > -1$. Then differentiate.